# How can I append div elements on the count of rows without getting duplicate content?

Tags: jquery, duplicates, append

I am trying to read the number of rows in a table and based on the amount of rows (minus the first four). I want to create div elements with some more data picking inside. But every time it creates two wrong divs after the first two right elements and then 3 wrong after the third one and so on. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```js
var bestellformular;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://rsabaugmbh.de/wp-content/uploads/bestellformular.csv",
  bestellformularType: "text",
  success: function(response) {
    bestellformular = $.csv.toArrays(response);
    generateHtmlTable(bestellformular);
  }

});

// Generates HTML Table out of CSV Table
function generateHtmlTable(bestellformular) {
  var html = '<table id="produkttabelle" class="produkttabelle">';

  if (typeof(bestellformular[0]) === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  } else {
    $.each(bestellformular, function(index, row) {

      html += '<tr>';
      $.each(row, function(index, colbestellformular) {
        html += '<td>';
        html += colbestellformular;
        html += '</td>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';
    alert(html);
    $('#csv-changes').append(html);
  };



  // Creates Products based on the CSV Table
  var product = '<div class="main_info_inner">';
  var rowCount = $('#produkttabelle tr').length - 4;
  alert(rowCount);

  if (typeof(bestellformular[0]) === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  } else {

    $.each(bestellformular, function(index, tr) {
      product += '<div class="product_image product_element"><img src="img/image_missing_error.png" alt=""/></div>';
      product += '<div class="product_title product_element"><p>HLP Asian Saladbowl m.Thai-Fal</p><p class="summe_alt">Summe Alt: 20</p><p class="summe_neu">Summe Neu: 18</p></div>';
      product += '<div class="add_product"><img src="img/add_row.png" alt=""/></div></div>';


      $('#main_info').append(product);


    });
  };

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#lieferdatum").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"


  });
  $("#lieferdatum").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
  $("#lieferdatum").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);



  // Lieferdatum & Maschinen-Anzahl
  $("#create_table").click(function() {

    var lieferdatum = $('#lieferdatum').val();
    var maschinen = $('#maschinen').val() - 1;


    // Lieferdatum
    $('#produkttabelle').find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:eq(2)').html(lieferdatum);





  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  font-family: arial;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#csv-changes table {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#csv-changes tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#csv-changes table tr td {
  height: 30px;
}

#csv-changes table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#create_table {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#create_table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.main_info {
  background: white;
  max-width: 1450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.datum {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.main_info_inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1360px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #dddddd;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.main_info_inner:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.main_info_inner.added {
  background: #F3FFEE;
  border-color: #1FC243;
}

.product_element {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product_table {
  background: white;
  max-width: 70%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.product_table table tbody tr {
  text-align: center;
}

.product_table table tbody tr:first-child {
  background: #97d9ff;
}

.product_table table tbody tr:nth-child(even):not(:first-child) {
  background: #ffe097;
}

.product_image,
.product_title {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.summe_alt {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.summe_neu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.add_product img {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.add_product img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/1.0.21/jquery.csv.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/date-picker.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <title>Bestellungen</title>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="main_info" class="main_info">
    <form class="datum">
      <label for="lieferdatum">Lieferdatum (DD.MM.YYYY):</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lieferdatum" name="lieferdatum"><br>
      <div id="create_table">Produkte erzeugen</div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="main_info_inner" class="main_info_inner"></div>
  <div class="container" id="csv-changes">
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#lieferdatum").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/script1.0.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

UPDATE: 26.06.22

1. List item
2. Reading CSV Table and create a HTML table
3. User enters "delivery date" at the top - this delivery date will be appended to the created HTML table
4. Creating  elements based on the CSV content like: Product Image, Product Name, Location Number
5. The created  elements can be selected like: select this product with a "+"
6. The selected  will get as a product into the HTML table
7. After the user selected all products that are needed he can export export the HTML table  as a CSV file and one file will be saved on the server. The CSV file name is going to be "bestellformular"+input from date of delivery

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies here:

```js
$('#produkttabelle').find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:eq(2)').html(lieferdatum);
```

when you think about it I you see why it's happening, it's saying, do 1 item and skip 2:

```
item 1
skip 
skip 
item 2 <-end point
```

then add 1 to end point again and skip 2, so end point has 2 item and thus it repeats

rather than eq, would a nth-of-type() Selector be better?

```
$('.myclass:nth-child(3n)')
```

see https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/

or use an each method, get the index and do a if ((index + 1) % 1 == 0) type check

a bit like

```js
$('myclass').each(function(i) {
     if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0){
     //every 4th item do something
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. The part of the code that you commented on is resposible for entering a date into a table that is not on the image from my post. It seems to work fine. But generating this part:
// Creates Products based on the CSV Table
seems to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes sorry i miss understood sorry my bad, I wasn't 100% sure what you were after as your end result but here is an example that will add the date picker to every 4th item (counting 0 as 1)

```js
var bestellformular;
// Generates HTML Table out of CSV Table
function generateHtmlTable(bestellformular) {
  var html = '<table id="produkttabelle" class="produkttabelle">';
  if (typeof(bestellformular[0]) === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  } else {
    $.each(bestellformular, function(index, row) {
      html += '<tr>';
      $.each(row, function(index, colbestellformular) {
        html += '<td>';
        html += colbestellformular;
        html += '</td>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';
    $('#csv-changes').append(html);
  };
  var rowCount = $('#produkttabelle tr').length - 4;
  if (typeof(bestellformular[0]) === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  } else {
    $.each(bestellformular, function(index, tr) {
      let product = `<div class="main_info_inner">
      <div class="product_image product_element">
      <img src="img/image_missing_error.png" alt=""/>` + index + `</div>
      <div class="product_title product_element">
      <p>HLP Asian Saladbowl m.Thai-Fal</p><p class="summe_alt">Summe Alt: 20</p>
      <p class="summe_neu">Summe Neu: 18</p></div>`

      //Add somthing diffrent ever 4th item assuming your counting 0 as 1
      if ((index % 3) === 0 && index > 0) {
        product += '<input type="text" id="lieferdatum" class="lieferdatum" name="lieferdatum" /><br>'
      }
      product += '<div class="add_product"><img src="img/add_row.png" alt=""/></div></div>';
      $('#main_info').append(product);
      $(".lieferdatum").datepicker();
    });
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //debugger;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://rsabaugmbh.de/wp-content/uploads/bestellformular.csv",
    bestellformularType: "text",
    //secure: true,
    success: function(response) {
      bestellformular = $.csv.toArrays(response);
      generateHtmlTable(bestellformular);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (console && console.log) {
      console.log("Sample of data:", data.slice(0, 100));
    }
  }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown)
  });

  $(".lieferdatum").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
  });
  $(".lieferdatum").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
  $(".lieferdatum").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);
  // Lieferdatum & Maschinen-Anzahl
  $("#create_table").click(function() {
    var lieferdatum = $('#lieferdatum').val();
    var maschinen = $('#maschinen').val() - 1;
    // Lieferdatum
    $('#produkttabelle').find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:eq(2)').html(lieferdatum);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  font-family: arial;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#csv-changes table {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#csv-changes tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#csv-changes table tr td {
  height: 30px;
}

#csv-changes table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#create_table {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#create_table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.main_info {
  background: white;
  max-width: 1450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.datum {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.main_info_inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1360px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #dddddd;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.main_info_inner:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.main_info_inner.added {
  background: #F3FFEE;
  border-color: #1FC243;
}

.product_element {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product_table {
  background: white;
  max-width: 70%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.product_table table tbody tr {
  text-align: center;
}

.product_table table tbody tr:first-child {
  background: #97d9ff;
}

.product_table table tbody tr:nth-child(even):not(:first-child) {
  background: #ffe097;
}

.product_image,
.product_title {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.summe_alt {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.summe_neu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.add_product img {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.add_product img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/1.0.21/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="main_info" class="main_info">
    <form class="datum">
      <label for="lieferdatum">Lieferdatum (DD.MM.YYYY):</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lieferdatum" class="lieferdatum" name="lieferdatum"><br>
      <div id="create_table">Produkte erzeugen</div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="main_info_inner" class="main_info_inner"></div>
  <div class="container" id="csv-changes">
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope this help, if not can you mock up an image or something to show the end result your after

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not exactly what i wanted to do. I better make a to-do list of my plan. I've updated the question above

Comment: could to standardize you csv file it doesn't seem to have consistent data as the data in the columns doesn't match up throughout. The columns need to always be consistent and in the same order even if empty. So if the column structure of your csv was always  product_id;product_image;product_location;
 it would make building the table much easier as you's know where the data was when building the table.
This is what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/zn1v24tk/ but not sure what you mean by "the selected will get as a product into the HTML table"

Comment: Thanks you for the help, the csv file is not created by me and is send to us by the company that we order from. So i want to read that csv to know which new products are inside and at what price. Then i wanted to give a member of our team the opportunity to select the needed products from the created DIVS and the selected products should go into the HTML Table created from the CSV. And finally export the new created HTML Table into a new CSV file that we can send to the company we order from.

Comment: in that case, you probably want the jquery-csv library, see https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv  , an example can be seen here https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Parsing-Displaying-CSV-Files-jQuery/
As the CSV is inconsistent and I don't know how it has been mapped it be impossible to wire anything up, the https://jsfiddle.net/zn1v24tk/ should give you an idea to build on though. If you know what column to look at in the CSV to get the data you want the rest is easy but the CSV has to be in a meaningful format